# VB Script (VBS) Add message to log file, each time it appears

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a simple vbs script which displays that the file is uploded:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
messageText = objArgs(0)
SDateTime = WeekdayName(Weekday(Date)) & ", " & MonthName(Month(Date()), False) & " " & Day(Date ()) & ", " & Year(Date())
MsgBox messageText & (DateAdd("n",1,Now())), 16
```

All what I'm looking for is that information which is in message box:

```
MsgBox messageText & (DateAdd("n",1,Now())), 16
```

Will append to log file, so I will can come back to check when each file was uploaded.

This is BAT file.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "datafolder=xxx"
set "tempdatafolder=%temp%\tempdata"
set switches=/r:0 /w:0 /mir /ns /nc /ndl /np /njh /njs


robocopy %switches% "%datafolder%" "%tempdatafolder%"

if exist "%datafolder%\*xxx*.xlsx" (
cscript n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.vbs "xxx READY!!  "
echo XXX IS READY FOR PROSECCING
EXIT
) else (
timeout 5
goto :loop
)

goto :loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.vbs` file

```vbs
Option Explicit 

Dim messageText
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then 
        messageText = WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & " " & DateAdd("n", 1, Now())
        MsgBox messageText, 16
        WScript.StdOut.WriteLine messageText 
    End If
```

Inside `.bat` file

```dos
>>"logFile.log" cscript //nologo n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.vbs "xxx READY!!  "
```

That is, make the `.vbs` file not only show the message box, but also write the text to console. Inside batch file `cscript` execution is redirected so its output will be appended to the log file.

Another (not better) option (if you can live without the dialog icon) is to change the output method and call twice the `.vbs` script. So

`.vbs` file

```vbs
Option Explicit 

Dim messageText
    If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then 
        messageText = WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & " " & DateAdd("n", 1, Now())
        WScript.Echo messageText
    End If
```

Inside `.bat` file

```dos
>>"logFile.log" cscript //nologo n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.vbs "xxx READY!!  "    
wscript n:\xxx\xxx\xxx.vbs "xxx READY!!  "
```

When the `.vbs` file is executed under `wscript.exe`, the `WScript.Echo` method shows a message box, but when executed under `cscript.exe` it outputs text to the console (that is redirected in the batch file).

Comment: Where LogFile.log will be created?

Comment: @MRSample, where you indicate, `>>"x:\somewhere\file.log"` for an absolute path, `>>".\file.log"` for a path relative to the current active directory, `>>"%~dp0\file.log"` for the folder where the batch file is stored, ... you decide

Comment: Why do you indent your statements under your `Dim`s? It's so jarring.

Comment: @Lankymart, just the habit to visually diferentiate declaration from the code that makes use of the declared elements. I also have the mania of using the javascript's lowerCamelCase naming for most of the declarations. I know I don't follow VBScript conventions, but for me it is easier to read and follow the code with separated declarations and a naming than make the variables stand out from the rest of VBscript language elements.

Comment: @Lankymart, ***`jarring`***.  First time I see it, thank you, one more for my vocabulary.

Comment: Just don't see the point of it, indentation on conditional statements etc makes sense to me but declarations always begin `Dim` so easy to spot. If I saw that, I'd assume it was a nested statement, which it isn't. It's all personal preference though.